# How do i find my mods folder on MacOS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, minecraft-mods

I recently tried downloading a mod, and found out my mods folder had disappeared. I wanted to try making a new folder but i realized that wouldn't do anything. I have been searching on the Internet to find a video about this, but rarely does a Minecraft mac website/video appear. Can anybody help me?

Comment: "but i realized that wouldn't do anything" Why? That's exactly what the instructions say. "but rarely does a Minecraft mac website/video appear" Have you tried adding the search term "mac"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you find your Minecraft folder at all? If you can't, exit all applications and press Command+Shift+G. A box will appear that says "Go to folder:". Type ~/Library/ and press Enter. Once you are in the Library folder, go to Application Support. Your Minecraft folder should appear there.
If that's not the problem, can you describe what is the problem in more detail?